# Override route values with user preferences values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route which has default values for a search, e.g. Sort=new and show=all

In my web app, each authenticated user has their own preferences where they can set their own default search criteria.

How do I make the route use the users values instead of the defaults specified in global.asax? E.g. Sort=cost and show=thisweek

I've tried a number of different things so far but to no avail

Comment: Wondering if base controller is what I need? Looks like I can modify route values there? Only problem is.... Since these route values have defaults, how will I know whether each value is to be overridden? If the URL explicitly says new for the sort, the user preference should not override it

Comment: OK, have implemented a base controller now for all my controllers and if I override the Execute method, I can now modify routevalues. This would be great if I could tell whether a route value has been specified or whether it is just using the default one from global.asax. If it is just using the default, I can replace with the users preference setting instead. Obviously if it is in the url, I don't want to replace this with the parameter. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get what I wanted using the BaseController and overridden Execute method.